# SimpleDateFormat - Do you need to use RegEx?

Tags: java, regex, date, simpledateformat

I have the code below, which produces this:

```
2012-07-28 17:30:23
```

Which is what I want. But if I want to extract all the numbers on their own to assign to variables, do I need to make a RegEx or is there some way to simply extract these from the SimpleDateFormat?

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUCT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 dateFormatUCT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UCT"));

 //Time in UCT
 String date = dateFormatUCT.format(new Date());

 System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: What number you want to assign to a variable..can you please include an example

Comment: Take a look at the [`parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) method of SimpleDateFormat when you just have a string representation of the date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a Date. Convert if to a [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html), and ask every field to the GregorianCalendar:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UCT")); // or UTC?
cal.setTime(theDate); // if you want something other than the current date
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // months start at 0, duh!
...
```

Comment: Why month + 1?  0 = Calendar.JANUARY

Comment: Because if he wants the same number as in the formatted date string, he wants 1 for January (as everyone in the world except the designer of GregorianCalendar would want).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a regex. You just take the Date and give it to a Calendar, then use the `get()` method to get each of the fields.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
c.setTime(new Date());

System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

etc.

Comment: Does this allow you to get the time and seconds as well?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract them from `SimpleDateFormat` afaik, but you could use `Java.util.Calendar` to extract the date components using its `get(Calendar.{DAY_OF_MONTH|MONTH|YEAR|HOUR|MINUTE|SECOND})` method. The `Calendar` object provides a `setTime()` method that takes a date. So, you could use the same date to format using `SimpleDateFormat` and to extract date components using the `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use `split()` method

**2.**  Do it like this...

```
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

  String[] arr = s.split(" ");

  String newDStr = arr[0];

  String newTStr = arr[1];

  String[] DateArr = newDStr.split("-");       // Holds Date values.
  String[] TimeArr = newTStr.split(":");       // Holds Time values
```

Comment: This is how I have done it at the moment. But it seems a long way around doing it. Is it the quickest way to get both times and dates?

Comment: Well not sure about quickest, but thats something good for building logics... he he....